# How can I define a parsing grammar in Perl 5?

Tags: perl, parsing, raku

I recently decided to look at Perl, and when faced with Perl 5 vs 6, I went with 5 due to its maturity and vast support.

However, one of the features of Perl 6 which really intrigued me was the [`grammar` keyword](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars), allowing one to define a language grammar which can be used to parse complex text. In other languages either an external library or a manual parsing implementation is usually needed for this.

Now that I've settled on Perl 5, is there any rough equivalent to Perl 6's `grammar` keyword in Perl 5 (or other functionality for building grammars), built-in or otherwise?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Grammars is one of the CPAN modules that does something similar. There are some answers here on SO by the author, Damian Conway, that use it extensively. But unfortunately your question is off-topic because you're asking for a tool recommendation.

Comment: @simbabque You can reword the question slightly to make it on-topic: "How can I define a grammar for parsing text in Perl 5?"

Comment: I know. But I figured the OP is experienced enough to do that themselves @ThisSuitIsBlackNot ;)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no core support, but you can have a look at [Parse::RecDescent](http://p3rl.org/Parse::RecDescent), [Marpa::R2](http://p3rl.org/Marpa::R2), [Regexp::Grammars](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Grammars), or for simpler tasks, just use `(DEFINE)` in a regex (see [perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre)).

Comment: They all look like good modules, especially `Regexp::Grammars`. Would you mind explaining a bit about `(DEFINE)` though please? The *perlre* docs for it seem a bit confusing for a beginner.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81: See [JSON parser as a single Perl Regex](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=995856) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Though I haven't used it much myself, I believe that the Acmeist software [Pegex](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pegex) is close to Perl 6 Grammars.